# If ID exists, find anchor tag and add class

Tags: jquery, css

I have an array of Vimeo iframes on my site which, on refresh, gets called randomly from the array. Each of these iframes have unique IDs.

What I'm after is depending on which iframe is displayed, it'll recognise the ID and add a class to the menu item.

So far I have this:

```
$("#yuan-photofilm").find(".menu-nav li ul li a").addClass('active-vimeo');
```

My thinking is that if `#yuan-photofilm` exists, it'll find `.menu-nav li ul li a` and add the class `.active-vimeo` - but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
R

Here's some of the HTML

```
<div class="grid_7 suffix_5">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe id="jack-photofilm" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46822673?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>   </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_7">
        <ul class="menu-nav">
            <li class="current-menu-nav-item"><a href="index.php">Photofilms</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#yuan" id="yuan">Yuan Shuai</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nina" id="nina">Nina</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#zhuoer" id="zhuoer">Zhuoer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#qingqing" id="qingqing">Uncle Douglas and Qingqing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#jack" id="jack">Jack</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li><a href="still.php">Photographs</a></li>
            <li class="sub-info-menu"><a href="information.php">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://blog.youziproject.com">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is `.menu-nav li ul li a` actually inside `#yuan-photofilm` or is it somewhere else in your HTML ?

Comment: There might be an easier way to do this. Can you post a little more code?

Comment: can you please show html structure of your document..

Comment: Apologies for not including the HTML. Added to original post now. #yuan-photofilm is not in the menu-nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each  element seems to have an ID, why not just target that ?

```
if ($("#yuan-photofilm").length) {
   $("#yuan").addClass('active-vimeo');
}
```

or more dynamic:

```
$('.menu-nav li ul li a').each(function(i,e) {
    if ($('#'+e.id+'-photofilm').length) $(e).addClass('active-vimeo');
});
```

Comment: Can I make this more dynamic?

`if ($("#yuan-photofilm").length) {
 $(".menu-nav li ul li a#yuan").addClass('active-vimeo');
}
if ($("#nina-photofilm").length) {
 $(".menu-nav li ul li a#nina").addClass('active-vimeo');
}
if ($("#zhuoer-photofilm").length) {
 $(".menu-nav li ul li a#zhuoer").addClass('active-vimeo');
}
if ($("#qingqing-photofilm").length) {
 $(".menu-nav li ul li a#qingqing").addClass('active-vimeo');
}
if ($("#jack-photofilm").length) {
 $(".menu-nav li ul li a#jack").addClass('active-vimeo');
}`

Comment: Yes, see the second example, that should do exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone is missing the point of jQuery selectors. Just use:

```
$("#yuan-photofilm .menu-nav li ul li a").addClass('active-vimeo');
```

​
If `#yuan-photofilm` doesn't exist then the selector will fail and the class will not be added. This can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/LtwW5/

**EDITED**

Having seen your HTML you can change this to either of these:

```
$("#yuan-photofilm").addClass('active-vimeo');
$(".menu-nav li ul li a#yuan-photofilm").addClass('active-vimeo');
```

depending on how strict you want to be with structure (e.g. if `#yuan-photofilm` occurs elsewhere use the second, it shouldn't since it's an id but thats not always the case with generated code)